# JSF file upload: commandLink not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2, commandlink

Sorry for my english. Does not work `<h:commandLink>` with `<f:ajax>`.

`test.xhtml`:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">

    <h:inputFile id="file" label="file" value="#{testMB.file}" required="true">
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="fileMessage"/>
    </h:inputFile>

    <h:message for="file" id="fileMessage" styleClass="message-error"/>

    <h:outputText value="#{testMB.date}" id="date" />

    <h:commandLink action="#{testMB.upload}">
        <f:ajax execute="file" render="fileMessage date" />
        upload
    </h:commandLink>

</h:form>
```

Class `TestMB`:

```
@ManagedBean(name="testMB")
@ViewScoped
public class TestMB {

    private Part file;

    public String date;

    public void upload() {

        try{
            Thread.sleep(Long.valueOf("5000"));
            this.date = "1111111111111111111";
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Part getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Part file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

I open `test.xhtml` and choose a file. If I click on link "upload", then sending is not working. If you click again, the link will not work, need to reload this page.

If I open page `test.xhtml` and choose a file. And I click on "empty space" to work checking `<f:ajax event="blur" render="fileMessage"/>`. And if I click on link "upload", then sending is working.

What is the problem? Please help me.

Comment: You tagged [jsf-2]. File upload using `<h:inputFile>` requires JSF 2.2 which in turn requires a minimum of Servlet 3.0 (a minimum of JDK 1.6). `<h:inputFile>` internally uses this Servlet API (3.0 or higher) to upload files without the need to have third party libraries. What versions of JSF and Servlet do you happen to use?

Comment: I use servlet 3.1.0 and JSF 2.2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated JSF 2.2.4 to JSF 2.2.6. If I choose a file and click on link "upload", then sending is not working. But if I click again, then sending is working.

I changed `<f:ajax event="blur" render="fileMessage"/>` to `<f:ajax event="change" render="fileMessage"/>`. And sending is working with the first click.